# application run slowly under uwsgi threaded mode

Tags: python, memcached, uwsgi

we use uwsgi + nginx to build the web site. recently, we want to improve the qps of our site, so we decide to switch uwsgi mode from prefork to threaded. but we found something very bad.

when using prefork mode with workers setting 5, we get the request time is 10-20ms. but in threaded mode(one worker 5 threads), the value increase to 100-200ms. this is too bad.

we find memcache.Client take the most time which makes the request time increasing.

please help me to know where the problem is and how to solve, thank you!

PS:
code:
import memcache
client = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'])
client.get('mykey')

Comment: Don't use threads. It's GIL problem

Try my variant 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755343/1865653

Answer (score 0):

You are probably experiencing the python GIL overhead. Try adding a second process to see if results are better.

Comment: i change to two workers 10 threads, the problem is still exist

Comment: under preforking mode, 41 times memcache query takes 21ms, but in preforking+threaded mode, it takes 110ms. the code is same.

Comment: which memcached module are you using ?  Try to use pylibmc as its management of the GIL is a lot better than python-memcached