# Django wsgi process cpu usage

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, cpu-usage, wsgi

Django wsgi processes on my server is taking large amount of cpu causing the server load to go high. Is there any tweak I can do on the server to prevent this?

=========================

PID  USER       PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
10408 user1  21   0  659m  57m 5764 S 74.9  0.5 122:32.27 (wsgi:daily)         -k start -DSSL
10409 user1  22   0  727m 127m 5784 S 49.2  1.0 122:39.94 (wsgi:daily)         -k start -DSSL
10410 user  22   0  659m  57m 5736 S 37.3  0.5 122:40.55 (wsgi:daily)         -k start -DSSL
10414 user1  24   0  659m  58m 5852 S 33.3  0.5 122:55.24 (wsgi:daily)         -k start -DSSL
10404 user1  20   0  659m  57m 5664 S 23.1  0.5 123:05.53 (wsgi:daily)         -k start -DSSL

=========================

I am using Django==1.3.1 and python2.7 for the setup.

## I am using below configuration as well

WSGIDaemonProcess [projectname] user=[username] group=[username] processes=5 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

====

Comment: Are your server real busy or just idle?

Comment: Consideration of using some performance monitoring tools to understand where bottlenecks and issue are would be a good start. There is no where near enough information in what you have provided to speculate on what the issue is. Knowing throughput is a good start, but there are so many other parameters that come into play. For some discussion on how to identify issues go watch http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

Comment: Try not use threads, may be you have problem GIL. And may be try variant nginx+uwsgi. Example config for uwsgi - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755343/1865653